# Writeablebitmap reading in an asynchronous call

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher, writeablebitmap

I want to pass a writeablebitmap object generated from UI (WPF) into an asynchronous call but don't want to update the main thread's writeablebitmap. I just want to read some properties such as pixel height and width. In the new thread I can't access any of the writeablebitmap's properties since it thinks I'm trying to mess with the main thread's writeablebitmap's properties. I receive the exception: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." Some responses in other threads suggested they use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, but if I just want a copy of the writeablebitmap object to read data from, is this necessary?

Comment: `Freezables` lose their thread-affinity when they're freezed. try calling `.Freeze()` in the `WritableBitmap`. Otherwise you can create a clone by using `.Clone()` and then freeze the clone.

Comment: please mark my  answer as accepted if it was useful you you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Freezables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx) lose their [Thread-affinity](http://vkishorekumar.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/what-is-thread-affinity/) when they're freezed. try calling [`Freeze()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.freeze.aspx) in the WritableBitmap.

Otherwise you can create a clone by using [`Clone()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.clone.aspx) and then freeze the clone